# Filter data in SQL or in Java?

Tags: java, sql, filter

What is the general guideline/rule for filtering data? I am accustomed to seeing filters in an SQL statement in the WHERE clause, although there are occasions that filters introduce complexity to the SQL, making it massive and abit hard to read on first glance for intermediate developers, but well-written ones that look complex are well-tuned and optimal. Filtering can also be done in Java, but that of course has a drawback where unfiltered data from SQL can be huge and loading it in memory only to filter it out may be wasteful. Of course there are cases where you have no choice but to filter in Java if you have several datasources as dependencies that the filter requires.

Comment: It depends?  I can imagine situations where either application-side (Java) or database-side (SQL) filtering would be ideal.... depending on the size of the data, how many round trips would be required, what is the overhead of running the query each time the filter changes... etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Filter on the backend (sql), whenever possible.  If that makes the query too complex for a junior developer then so be it.  While clarity of code is important, you shouldn't make design decisions based on how well a junior developer will understand it -- its sufficient that he be able to use it.

This is particularly the case when talking about different layers, your junior developer might not know any SQL, would you then avoid a SQL backend entirely?

Write your SQL to be as clear as possible (without sacrificing performance), but do so with the expectation that the person maintaining it will be familiar with SQL and how it should be used.  When crossing layers like this, a little "easier to understand" can really kill your performance (pulling data back from the db in order to update it, can take thousands of times longer than a update on the DB, inappropriate use of a cursor can be expoentally worse than a set based solution).

Comment: Thanks for the input, my question was a little along this line, performance vs readability/maintainability. I think its a good guideline to consider first amongst other factors.

Comment: @CarlosJaimeC.DeLeon: It is an important consideration WITHIN a layer, but not across layers.  Across layers, excluding really lousy performance, the most important thing to consider is appropriateness; should it be handled at this layer or that.  Within the layer, readability should be considered slightly more important than performance.  But if you've decided your business logic is best done in lisp, don't skip on your business logic just because most of your developers are more familar with vbscript/java/F#, whatever.

Comment: Just a little thing, doesn't filtering all small things on SQL put a great amount of business logic on data access layer?

Comment: @user1186523: not really.  The data tier already knows about the data structure, you simply provide standard terms(typically keys) for filtering the data that would be returned.

Comment: @jmoreno For example, if you write a getUnpaidInvoices method in data access layer, aren't you putting business logic on it? Being unpaid is a business logic but you can't join tables in the service layer...

Comment: @Reek: no, being unpaid is a data state.  Business logic is where you determine whether or not to go from one state to another.  UnpaidInvoices is actually a good example of where you'd want to do it in the db--a large business could easily have 1000 times as many paid as unpaid invoices. Loading them all just to then discard them is waste.

Comment: What about cases where the java side is load balanced but the db server isn't?

Comment: @raisinghope: the db is probably going to expend more resources returning the unfiltered results than it would filtering and just returning what is needed, in which case you are putting a greater demand on it when you don't have it filter.

Comment: In general I agree with you, but in some cases it can be advisable to prefer Java, because testing with unit test is easier than testing the SQL query.

Answer (score 5):

If the data is already in the DB, then it makes more sense to do the filtering within it, since the RDBMS will be optimized for this kind of work. If the filtering can be confusing to novice and intermediate developers, why not hide it in a view, and only grant access to the view, to the users in question?

Answer (score 2):

I guess there are no definite answers to it. It depends of individual use case. Both filtering in java as well as SQL can be applicable depending on the application under consideration.

- As you mentioned, filtering in SQL can make the queries complex and and costly. But at the same this can be improved using database tuning, putting appropriate indexes, table partitioning etc. This is specially the case where in the database design is still evolving and you can do these type of changes.
- if you are working on a system whose database is already designed and you have hardly any scope for significant changes (and hence not much query/database optimization), in this case filtering in java is better option.

It all depends on specific use case.

Comment: The cases where filtering in "Java" is better are so rare as to be not worth mentioning. Filtering at the DB level is usually faster than getting all the data then filtering and is *never* slower.

Comment: Yes. such cases are indeed rare and if you need that then it implies some problem in the DB schema design. Also as OP mentions, if you are dealing with several data sources then this becomes a necessity.